# HP Elitebook 8440p fan stuck on max

Tags: fan, hp-elitebook

I have an Elitebook 8440p fan that spins at the high setting all the time. When I opened it up, I see a 3 wire connector. How do I fix it?

Comment: Have you checked the temperatures?

Comment: @gronostaj It doesn't feel hot

Comment: Have a look in the BIOS for fan profile. It's a 3-pin PWM fan, so can be speed-controlled by the BIOS.

Comment: @spikey_richie the only way to turn off the fan is to unplug its connector.

Comment: You want the fan to be running when the laptop is powered on. Check for a fan profile.

Comment: @spikey_richie The only fan setting I see is "Fan always on when on AC power".

Comment: It doesn't matter if it feels hot. It may not feel hot if the fan is doing its job. That doesn't mean that the fan is not necessary. Use HWINFO to read what temperature sensors are reporting.

Comment: @gronostaj it is 40C.

Comment: Which sensor was that? There are multiple temperature sensors in a laptop. We're mostly interested in the CPU sensor.

Comment: All cores @gronostaj